# paypal sandbox - verify identity

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am testing my payment integration using PayPal Sandbox

When I go to make  payment using a sandbox account, the following message displays on the payment page

> To use your balance next time, go to your PayPal account for an
> identity check.

If I log into the sandbox account, I am not seeing any way to do this.

How do I set up the sandbox account so that it can use PayPal funds for the payment rather than the credit card option?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how you are funding the payment in sandbox. There's no actual reason for you to be bothering to care about this issue, since the result of a completed PayPal payment on the receiver end will be identical.

But since you ask, you can create a bank verified account via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F